# React.js: modify render() method for all components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For debugging reasons I'd like to add following line into general render() method, so it would be executed in all components.

```
console.log('render' + this.constructor.displayName, this.state);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you add some more context to the question ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you want to do this without changing any of the existing code. I played around with this and found a way to do so *if* you're using something like webpack or browserify to build your application **and you're using React v0.13**.

**It's important to note that this uses private methods, reaching into React's internals, and could break at any time.** That said, it might be useful for your debugging purposes.

**[Update to the Update]**

If you use Babel, I *highly* recommend checking out [the React Transform plugin](https://github.com/gaearon/babel-plugin-react-transform). This will let you do all sorts of nifty stuff to React, including wrapping (or overwriting!) `render` methods.

**[Update]**

I've found a way to do this without hacking into `React.addons.Perf`; the key was the module name of `ReactCompositeComponent` and the function name of `_renderValidatedComponent`—just wrap that method to inject your custom behavior.

Note you'll need to place this code **before** you `require("react")`.

```
var ReactCompositeComponent = require("react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent");
var oldRenderValidatedComponent = ReactCompositeComponent.Mixin._renderValidatedComponent;
ReactCompositeComponent.Mixin._renderValidatedComponent = function() {
  var name = this.getName();
  if (name && !name.match(/^ReactDOM/)) {
    console.log("render: ", this.getName(), {props: this._instance.props, state: this._instance.state});
  }
  return oldRenderValidatedComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

You'll then end up with a very similar result as the old answer, below. I've added better logging of props and state, and filter out any of the built in `ReactDOM*` components.

[image: Example]

---

**[Old Answer]**

I've overridden the default `measure` function of the performance tools, which React calls through its codebase to measure performance when using `React.addons.Perf`. By doing so, we're able to get the information that the default measurement strategy would normally get. Note that this breaks the normal behavior `React.addons.Perf`.

Add this code to the entry-point of your application (after you require React):

```
var ReactInjection = require("react/lib/ReactInjection");
var ReactDefaultPerf = require("react/lib/ReactDefaultPerf");

ReactDefaultPerf.start();
ReactInjection.Perf.injectMeasure(function measure(moduleName, fnName, fn) {
  return function() {
    if (moduleName === 'ReactCompositeComponent' && fnName === '_renderValidatedComponent') {
      var name = this.getName();
      if (name) {
        console.log("render: ", name);
      }
    }

    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

And you'll get the following in your console logs:

[image: Console]

`ReactElement`s with no names (that is, components that make up regular HTML elements like `span` and `div`) are not shown. One notable set of exceptions is `button` and other `input` elements, as React provides composite components that wrap those to help manage state. They show up as `ReactDOMButton` and `ReactDOMInput`.

Comment: sounds cool, but my suggestion was not only to log component name, but also it's current state. it's not possible to hijack internal render method?

Comment: @LadislavMaxa I'm not aware of any way—at least, not any way to *wrap* it. You still want React to render your stuff, but you *additionally* want to do other stuff too. At any rate, you can get access to the component's props and state in my hack with `this._instance.props` and `this._instance.state`.

Comment: @LadislavMaxa I've updated my answer with a slightly less hacky method, that may be more what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately ReactCompositeComponent no longer exists in the lib folder :(

Answer (score 0):

React supports Mixins for such cross-cutting concerns:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins

However, it's not permitted to define a `render` method in a mixin. The restrictions on each of the React lifecycle methods are in the following source:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0c6bee049efb63585fb88c995de788cefc18b789/src/core/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L189

If you could assign this behaviour to one of the other steps in the component lifecycle, mixins might work for you.