# React globally on render console.log the component name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a simple way to console.log React Component names every time they are rendered (including Pure Components). The requirement is that it log globally without having to put code in every component. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445568/react-js-modify-render-method-for-all-components) but the answer is outdated I believe because it doesn't work. I have also looked at why-did-you-update, but the output is way to verbose for the console. I am just looking for simple console logging, i.e.:

> rendering MyComponent1...
>
> rendering MyComponent2...

etc...

Comment: did you considered extending react.component and|or write a [higher order component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) which just logs the component name and renders the component u wish?

Comment: I don't know... I'm trying to avoid having to change 30+ components...

Comment: well using higher order components u have to change the files where ur using the component - not the component itself...  by extending React.Component u need at least change the extends from every component (as long as ur writing es6) which is just one/two words - find/replace done + writing the HOC ;)